# Web API Help page doesn't work with custom route

Tags: asp.net, api, rest, documentation-generation, asp.net-web-api-helppages

I have a problem with API help page, it works well until I changed the route of API.

Let see this example, I have a booking API for controlling users' booking action:

```
    public IEnumerable<Booking> Get(string token)
    {
        return BookingRepository.GetBooking(token);
    }

    public string Post([FromBody]AddBookingData data)
    {
        // Do something with the posted booking data
        return null;
    }
```

And I have a route for getting booking

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "GetBookingOfCustomer",
            routeTemplate: "api/Booking/{customerToken}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Booking", customerToken = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

So the generated page has only 1 documentation for booking, like this :

```
GET api/Booking/{customerToken}            Documentation for 'Get'.
```

There is no documentation for POST action. I don't know why.
Thank you so much !

Comment: I am unable to repro the issue with your above code...do you have any other routes apart from `GetBookingOfCustomer`?...also you probably meant `Get(string customerToken)` and not `Get(string token)`?